# what is the disadvantage in using mosfet at input stage?

Tags: mosfet, analog, integrated-circuit

[image: cascaded connection of transistors]In a cascade connection of mos transistor and Bipolar junction transistor ,what are the cons of using MOS transistor at input stage of the connection??

Answer (score 3):

In this circuit the NMOS is used to get a high **input impedance**.

The gate of a MOS transistor behaves as a (small) capacitor, it does not require any DC current.

Note that here the Gate is DC-biased at 0 Volt. Some DC current must be flowing through that MOSFET so the source will not be at 0 V DC due to the source resistor dropping some voltage.

So \$V_{gs}\$ of this MOSFET will be **negative** in this circuit!

That means that the NMOS must be a **[depletion type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_and_enhancement_modes)** (normally off) NMOS otherwise no current would flow and the amplifier would not work.

Although the schematic suggests that M1 is a MOSFET, a JFET (which are also normally) would also work.

In my opinion the MOSFET is not really needed.

You can also make a similar high-impedance input using BJTs, the circuit would have to be slightly different though. Many opamps have high impedance (about 1 M ohm) inputs using BJTs. One solution is to use a [Darlington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) configuration.

But you asked about pros and cons:

**Advantages of using MOS input:**

high input impedance

simple circuit

**Disadvantages:**

Could be more noisy, MOSFETs have more noise than BJTs, a JFET could be a good compromise, they are less noisy than BJTs

Hard to find. It will be difficult to **buy** a depletion mode NMOS as they are very rarely used. JFETs are easier to find. BJTs are very easy to find.

Comment: +1 Some RF small signal MOSFETs are depletion mode, for example the [BF1108](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BF1108_BF1108R.pdf). Unfortunately, many of them are now EOL (End Of Life in the product cycle) so not a good choice for new designs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare a BJT over a MOSFET here as the input stage and see which is better. First of all, if you look carefully, the source has a series resistance of 10k. The MOS has a very high input impedance at low frequency. Say it's 10M ohms. Now the impedance seen at the gate of MOS is 1M||10M which is roughly 1M.  Now the signal arriving at the gate of MOS attenuates by a factor of \$\frac{1M}{1M+10k}=1\$. This means that the signal arrives with no attenuation.

However, if you had used a BJT things would have become troublesome. The input impedance at the base of BJT would have been \$r_{\pi}\$, or \$\frac{\beta} {g_m}\$. Now for a \$\beta\$ of 100 and \$g_m\$ of 0.04, \$r_{\pi}\$ would have been calculated to be 2.5k ohms. Neglecting the 1M ohms resistor and associating a 1k ohms resistance at the base of BJT due to biasing resistors, the input signal would have seen 1k||2.5k= 0.7k ohms at the base. Now the signal arriving at the base of BJT attenuates by a factor of \$\frac{0.7k}{10k+0.7k}=0.07\$. So the signal is completely lost and effectively reduces the gain of the overall circuit. So I don't see any cons of using a MOS over BJT.

For next stages you can, however, use BJTs as you don't have this problem there. As this is designed for audio amplification the frequency response isn't a big deal here and both BJT and MOS work the same.

Also it's still possible to use a BJT at the first stage by carefully using a series resistance across C2 to increase the input impedance. Of course, in this case you have to pay for extra reduction in the gain. There are also many trade-offs which you'll have to consider when adding a series resistor.